# Mobiscroll date modal customisation

Tags: javascript, mobiscroll

Have a mobiscroll instance to show date:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {                               
                $("#date").mobiscroll().date({
                    theme: 'wp',
                    mode: 'clickpick',
                    onChange: function (ins) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(ins));
                    }
                });
            });
```

Currently the datepicker displayed in the format like: dd/mm/yyyy
How can swap the order be to see mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: What version of mobiscroll you are using?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date").mobiscroll().date({
        theme: 'wp',
        mode: 'clickpick',
        onChange: function (ins) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ins));
        },
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
});
```

Here's the link for more info:

https://docs.mobiscroll.com/3-1-0/jquery/datetime#!localization-dateFormat

Comment: Investigation shown dateFormat parm sets date of the input field, however in my instance solution was setting the lang param as: 
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#date").mobiscroll().date({
             lang: window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage, theme: 'wp',
             mode: 'clickpick',
             onChange: function (ins) {
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(ins));
             },
             dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
         });
      });